# UNIX batch shell script - will current command execute only after previous command finishes execution

Tags: shell, unix

If I have a UNIX shell script which has some program on each line that needs to be run, like

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
command2
command3
command4
```

will command2 execute only after command1 execution finishes or are they run in parallel without waiting for the previous command to finish as each command is a separate process that needs to be executed.

Comment: What happened when you tried executing your script?

Answer (score 0):

The commands are run serially.  To run them in parallel, append `&` to each line:

```
#!/bin/bash
command1&
command2&
command3&
command4&
wait
```